# Error when running 'npm start'

Tags: node.js, npm, error-handling, node-modules

This has been a consistent problem for me when running 'npm start' regardless of what framework I am working in. This is my output when I run 'npm start' on my local machine.

```
/Users/developer/dev-projects/Central-Repo/node_modules/rcloader/index.js:39
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.csslintrc'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! meanjs@0.6.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the meanjs@0.6.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/developer/.npm/_logs/2018-07-24T06_12_40_636Z-debug.log
```

What am I missing here? I have uninstalled and reinstalled all node modules. I have done my research and every proposed solution I find doesn't work for me.

Comment: Your node application not able to Read './config/assets/default' path. add correct path in module.js then it's work.

Comment: Where is my .config/assets/default file located? Is it supposed to be within the project repo or is it somewhere else. I found the module.js file, but its in the node_modules/di/lib/module.js path. I am still a bit confused.

Comment: please update your code where you using config/assets/default and project hierarchy view

Comment: I can't find anywhere in my project where config/assets/default is. A screenshot may help explain the problem here. There are so many node modules I don't know where to start looking for this path within my project.

Comment: Try to do a global search in your project, looking for a *require* instruction, such as *require('./config/assets/default')*. This is specific to your project, not NPM related.

Comment: Add your porject directory in Post.